# Fix Git Annotate For Project Migrated From Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

I've been working with a third party repository called [collect](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect) for the past week or so. One annoying thing about the repository is that running `git annotate` on pretty much anything in the project attributes the changes to a [single commit in January](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/tree/db28500c38ff2b017a4acdec5900fc563407c687)

Here's a screenshot of the tree:
[image]

I don't have any experience with mercurial work flows or with converting mercurial projects to git although I have previously read about them.

Best I can tell, this repository used to use Mercurial but now uses git. I don't have access to the original Mercurial repository.

To me, it looks like either the merges were in the wrong direction or the lack of a parent for so many of the *Merge with x* commits.

Is there anything I can do to modify my copy of the repository so that `git annotate` will show the proper history of files?

Comment: Is your repository supposed to have multiple roots (commits with no parents)?  Because that's... *not* the normal way of structuring things.

Comment: @Kevin I've never seen a repository like this either. I suspect the multiple roots were a side effect of importing the mercurial repo into git.

Comment: How did you import this?  Did you only grab commits from the default branch or something?

Comment: @Kevin I didn't import it, it was created by a [third party](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect).

Comment: Please, show how "git annotate ... attributes the changes to a single commit..." - I cloned repo, tried *some* annotates and get expected results. Anyway, repository was converted in no-brain style and have "root per branch" log (not recoverable in easy way)

Answer (score 0):

**I Fixed It**, here's what I've learned. After I had [contacted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opendatakit-developers/6yTV_igSEeY) the third party that maintains this software, they told me they were trying to reconvert all their other repositories too, so I'm posting this to help anyone who needs to reconvert a mercurial repository to git and replay commits from the old repository to the new one.

### Reconvert the original mercurial repo to git

These bad mercurial to git conversions are caused by github's import tool. So don't use it. (although maybe it will be improved in the future) I contacted the developers and got the original mercurial repository. I used [fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export) which worked great, but only when I tried it on Ubuntu.

### Rebase Commits Made In Git

#### Add the repository that you want to rebase commits from as a remote.

```
git remote add other https://github.com/opendatakit/collect.git
git fetch other
```

#### Rebase

Determine the sha of the last commit on the other branch that was made while it was a mercurial repo. In my case, that commit is `10c98fb4de35e5342dff7bdae22cd2b192d7a8cd`

now rebase, preserving the original authors and dates:

```
git rebase 10c98fb4de35e5342dff7bdae22cd2b192d7a8cd other/master --onto master --committer-date-is-author-date
```

now you'll need to move your local master to point to head

```
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

After that you can remove the remotes you added.